# Make Frama-c show dependencies even of "dead branches"

Tags: frama-c, dependency-analysis

I am using frama-c Aluminium-20160502 version and I want to find out the dependencies in a large program. When using the option -deps in the command line I found some dependencies are missing. In particular when several conditions are joined in one if, the dependency analysis stops whenever one condition is false. In this example here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

/*Global variable definitions*/
bool A = true;
bool B = false;
bool C = true;
bool X;
bool Y;

bool res;


void main(){

        if (A && B && C) {
                res = X;
        }else res = Y;
}
```

when I try: `frama-c -deps program.c`

frama shows the following dependencies:

[from] ====== DEPENDENCIES COMPUTED ======

These dependencies hold at termination for the executions that terminate:

[from] Function main:
  res FROM A; B; Y

[from] ====== END OF DEPENDENCIES ======

so it does not reach the condition C because already B is false.

I wonder if there is a way to tell frama to compute all dependencies even if the condition is not fulfilled. I tried with the option -slevel but with no results. I know there is a way to use an interval Frama_C_interval(0,1) but when I use it the variable using this function is not shown in the dependencies. I would like to get X and Y dependent on A,B,C and res dependent on A,B,C,X,Y

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that what you call a "dead branch" is a syntactic structure that has no semantic impact on the program execution (e.g. like `&& true`). Because Frama-C's dependency analyses are based on semantics, you'll probably have to either "fool" them into considering the extraneous branch (e.g. `volatile`, `Frama_C_interval`, etc.), or try devising a syntactic analysis (e.g. with a visitor) that would compute your notion of syntactic dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The From plugin uses the results of the Value analysis plugin. In your example, the values of `A` and `B` are sufficiently precise that Value is able to infer that the condition is entirely determined (since the `&&` operator is lazily evaluated, from left to right) before reaching `C`, therefore `C` never affects the outcome and is thus not a dependency from the point of view of From.

Unfortunately, `Frama_C_interval` cannot be used directly at global initializers:

```
user error: Call to Frama_C_interval in constant.
```

You can, however, use a "hack" (not always the best solution, but works here):

```
volatile bool nondet;
bool A = nondet;
bool B = nondet;
bool C = nondet;
...
```

Note that because `nondet` is `volatile`, each variable `A`, `B` and `C` is assigned a different non-deterministic value.

In this case, Value has to consider both branches of the conditionals, and therefore `C` becomes a dependency in your example, since it is possible that `C` will be read during the execution of `main`. You'll then have:

```
       These dependencies hold at termination for the executions that terminate:
[from] Function main:
  res FROM A; B; C; X; Y
```

Note that some plugins require special treatment when dealing with volatile variables, so this is not always the best solution.

This however only deals with some kinds of dependencies. As mentioned in Chapter 6 of the [Value Analysis user manual](http://frama-c.com/download/value-analysis-Aluminium-20160501.pdf), the From plugin computes functional, imperative and operational dependencies. These do **not** include indirect *control dependencies*, which are those such as `X from A, B, C`, as you mention. For those, you need the PDG (Program Dependence Graph) plugin, but it does not currently have a textual output of the dependencies. You can use `-pdg` to compute it, and then `-pdg-dot <file>` to export the dependency graph in dot (graphviz) format. Here's what I get for your `main` function (using the volatile hack as mentioned previously):

[image: PDG for the main function]

Finally, as a side note: `-slevel` is mostly used to *improve* precision, but in your example you already have *too much* precision (that is, Value is already able to infer that `C` is never read inside `main`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it was very helpfull. I tried with the -pdg option, but for larger programs is a bit messy to find the dependencies by eye. However is very interesting the volatile definition and solves already the problem if used for every variable.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution seems to work only partially because, whenever the value of A,B, or C is changed during the execution, then the lazy evaluation makes the dependencies away. So then I would need somehow to set this lazy evaluation off in a more general solution, in a way that Frama-C follows all possible execution paths.

Comment: Would it make sense to declare A, B and C as `volatile` themselves? Every read/write on them would be then non-deterministic. But this might change the semantics of your program in a way that is not the one intended.

Comment: Yes, it works just fine and all the conditions are reached in this way, thank you again!